# что лучше высылать: куки посетителя или авторизующие заголовки с данными из localstorage

Tags: сессия, авторизация, auth

пользователь отправил с формы POST запросом login и password
на сервере пользователь авторизовался, инициализировалось сессия и отправлен hash ключ пользователя

что лучше:

ключ сохранен в куках сервером

```
  или
```

ключ сохранен вручную в localstorage

что лучше после авторизации при каждом обращении:

клиент высылает куки браузера

```
  или
```

клиент высылает вручную ключ из localstorage в заголовках HTTP_Authorization

Comment: Пользователь у вас где работает? В браузере?

Comment: @Visman да, в браузере, берем какой - нибудь js framework и он должен общаться с сервером без server side rendering